# Can't call a StringVar from within a definition(Saving to a specific line in .csv based on dropdown)

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

The end goal is to have the code save to a certain line of a .csv file based on the selected number (1-6). This will be used as a rudimentary form of data validation to use a 6-line csv file, making it easier to call back individual lines for other functionality.I think that the code below is not wrapped correctly and so my calls to the StringVar 'tkvar' does not work (as it cannot be seen from within the definition?).

I've tried several different iterations of wrapping the code including an if statement that saved base on a selection, but all seems to fail due to the 'position/location' of WriteToFile and the inability to call tkvar from within.

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
import csv
import tkinter
import serial
from time import sleep, strftime, time

class SampleApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(AddMethod)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        #camera.stop_preview()
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

class AddMethod(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        title = Label(self, text="Method Settings").grid(row=0, column=1)
        a1 = Button(self, text='Back', height=5, width=20, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(ManMeth)).grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky='')
        a2 = Button(self, text='Save and Return to Analysis', height=5, width=20, command=lambda:[self.writeToFile, master.switch_frame(ManMeth)]).grid(row=3, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky='')
        a3 = Button(self, text='Save Method', height=5, width=20, command=self.writeToFile).grid(row=5, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky='')
        mthtit = Label(self, text="Method Title", font="12").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        sttemp = Label(self, text="Start Temperature", font="12").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        wttm = Label(self, text="Waiting Time", font="12").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        sktm = Label(self, text="Soaking Time", font="12").grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        endtemp = Label(self, text="End Temperature", font="12").grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
        htrt = Label(self, text="Heating Rate", font="12").grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
        tkvar = StringVar(self)
        choices = { '1','2','3','4','5','6'}
        tkvar.set('Select') # set the default option
        popupMenu = OptionMenu(self, tkvar, *choices)
        Label(self, text="Quicksave No#").grid(row=1, column=3)
        popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=4)
        # on change dropdown value
        def change_dropdown(*args):
            print(tkvar.get())
            # link function to change dropdown
        tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.checkbutton.configure(height=3)
        self.chklabel = Label(self)
        self.chklabel.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.chklabel.configure(text="Ramp to Starting Temperature", font="12")
        self.mthtite = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
        self.mthtite.grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.sttempe = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
        self.sttempe.grid(row=3, column=3)
        self.wttme = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
        self.wttme.grid(row=4, column=3)
        self.sktme = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
        self.sktme.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.endtempe = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
        self.endtempe.grid(row=6, column=3)
        self.htrte = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
        self.htrte.grid(row=7, column=3)
        sttemp1 = Label(self, text="°C", font="BOLD 12").grid(row=3, column=4, sticky=W)
        wttm1 = Label(self, text="Sec", font="BOLD 12").grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W)
        sktm1 = Label(self, text="MM:SS", font="BOLD 12").grid(row=5, column=4, sticky=W)
        endtemp1 = Label(self, text="°C", font="BOLD 12").grid(row=6, column=4, sticky=W)
        htrt1 = Label(self, text="°C/Min", font="BOLD 12").grid(row=7, column=4, sticky=W)

        buttons = [
            '~','`','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','Clear',
            'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P','0','7','8','9','Back',
            'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L','[',']','4','5','6','Tab',
            'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.','?','/','1','2','3','Space',
            ]

        def select(value):


            if value =="Clear":
                Entry.focus_get(self).delete(0, END)
            elif value == "Back":
                widget = Entry.focus_get(self)
                if widget:
                    widget.delete(widget.index("end")-1)
            elif value == "Space":
                Entry.focus_get(self).insert(END, ' ')
            elif value == "Tab":
                Entry.focus_get(self).insert(END, '    ')
            else :
                Entry.focus_get(self).insert(END, value)

        class Keyboard(Frame):
            def __init__(self, root):
                Frame.__init__(self, root)

                def HosoPop():

                        varRow = 2
                        varColumn = 0

                        for button in buttons:

                                command = lambda x=button: select(x)

                                if button == "Clear" or button == "Space" or button == "Tab" or button == "Back":
                                        Button(self,text= button,width=4, height=2, bg="white", fg="black", relief=RAISED,
                                                activebackground = "#ffffff", activeforeground="#3c4987",
                                                command=command).grid(row=varRow,column=varColumn)

                                else:
                                        Button(self,text= button,width=3, height=2, bg="white", fg="black", relief=RAISED,
                                                activebackground = "#ffffff", activeforeground="#3c4987",
                                                command=command).grid(row=varRow,column=varColumn)


                                varColumn +=1 

                                if varColumn > 14 and varRow == 2:
                                        varColumn = 0
                                        varRow+=1
                                if varColumn > 14 and varRow == 3:
                                        varColumn = 0
                                        varRow+=1
                                if varColumn > 14 and varRow == 4:
                                        varColumn = 0
                                        varRow+=1
                HosoPop()

        keys  = Keyboard(self).grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=4)

    def writeToFile(self):
        mthd_list = []
        # Read all data from the csv file.
        with open('Working_MethodFile.csv', 'rb') as b:
            mthd = csv.reader(b)
            mthd_list.extend(mthd)

        # data to override in the format {line_num_to_override:data_to_write}. 
        line_to_override = {[tkvar.get()]:[self.mthtite.get(), self.sttempe.get(), self.wttme.get(), self.sktme.get(), self.endtempe.get(), self.htrte.get()] }

        # Write data to the csv file and replace the lines in the line_to_override dict.
        with open('Working_MethodFile.csv', 'wb') as b:
            writer = csv.writer(b)
            for line, row in enumerate(mthd_list):
                 data = line_to_override.get(line, row)
                 writer.writerow(data)

    #with open('Working_MethodFile.csv', 'a') as f:
     #   w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
      #  w.writerow([self.mthtite.get(), self.sttempe.get(), self.wttme.get(), self.sktme.get(), self.endtempe.get(), self.htrte.get()])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

currently the error "NameError: name 'tkvar' is not defined" is thrown when you try to save a file. it should save to the corresponding line selected in the dropdown box or throw an error if no dropdown is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddMethod` class's `__init__` function, where you set `tkvar = StringVar(self)`, you're making it a local variable. It's not a field of the class, and so once you exit the `__init__` function, you can't access it anymore, which explains the `NameError: name 'tkvar' is not defined` that you're getting.

For that variable, and all of the other ones that you want to use somewhere else, do `self.tkvar = StringVar(self)`, and then when you access them inside the class in different methods, you can do `self.tkvar`.

Comment: Won't this call a different variable and not return the value associated with the dropdown box? i.e. if i define a new stringvar within another class won't it hold a nil value?

EDIT: nvm i reread and realise the question sounds stupid, let me give this a try.

Comment: Upon implementation of your fix, i get the error 'TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not callable',